# LightGBM and pre-binned data

Tags: lightgbm

I have a huge dataset (takes ~ 75% of memory to load), with pre-binned features as a dense array of `int8_t`. LightGBM seems to either cast them to doubles, or if I specify that they're categorical, tries to cast them to `int32_t`s.

Is it possible to have lgb use the features directly as I've passed them in, without doing any extra copy/transform/histogram operations?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [forcedbins_filename](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Parameters.html#forcedbins_filename) helps.

You can specified all feature bin_upper_bound in range of 0~255.

It is impossible to bypass `copy/transform/histogram operations`/